# Build error - variable environment not set correctly

Tags: qt, qt4, environment-variables, qt4.8

I'm trying to build an opensource code on windows.
I get the error:

```
Warning: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as D;/Qt/4.8.4/lib
Warning: D**;**/Qt/4.8.4/lib does NOT exist, Qt must NOT be installed correctly.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.6.4/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:640 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find QtCore header
```

(this is only a part of the error message)

I tried to re-install Qt, didn't work.

I tried to change QT_INSTALL_LIBS to be D:/Qt/4.8.4/lib (and not D:/Qt/4.8.4/lib) in my computer -> properties -> advanced - > environment variables but that didn't seem to change a thing.

I have no idea what to do next. Does anyone know what I should do fix it?

Comment: QT_INSTALL_LIBs is returned by qmake, it's not an env. var. How did you install Qt? Best use the installer and not move it manually.

Comment: i did moved it manually.. I also tried to reinstall qt, but the code I downloaded only works with qt version 4.8.2 - which is no longer available online (ftp://ftp.qt-project.org/qt/source/).

Comment: also tried version 4.6.0 (- which my code works with also) - and i still get this error

Comment: Why does your code not work with 4.8.4? You error message above is also about 4.8.4.